# Batch file to delete duplicate shotcut links in a folder

Tags: batch-file, match, delete-file

I am trying to get a batch file that will look in `C:\users\public\desktop` and then delete any duplicate shortcut links like `Shortcut (1)` but leave the original.

Can something like this work? where you look at what files are in the directory and if it matches the file and has (1) or (2) at the end delete it. Example:

- myfilelink.lnk
- myfilelink (1).lnk
- myfile2.lnk
- myfile2 (1).lnk

then delete the ones with (1) at the end?

This is what I have so far but im not sure how to look at %%a and see if it has a (1) in the string. Then if it does Delete it.

```
@echo off
for /R "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Testing" %%a in (*.lnk) do IF %%a
PAUSE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `/s` if you want it to act recursively.

```
del "C:\users\public\desktop\*(1).lnk"
del "C:\users\public\desktop\*(2).lnk"
```

or this if you are sure of the match:

```
del "C:\users\public\desktop\*(?).lnk"
```

Comment: When I run this I get `Could Not Find C:\Users\user\Desktop\Testing\*(1).lnk`

Comment: You don't have that filespec in that location.

Comment: I do its on my desktop with 10 shortcut links in the folder.

Comment: `dir "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Testing\*.lnk"` <--- this will tell you if you have those files there.  The error message is very clear.

Comment: Awesome thank you! I guess I was trying to make it a lot harder than it needed to be!